# regex in python with defined number of letters but no more

Tags: python, regex

I need to check whether the string contains exactly three letters-no more, no les.

I tried:

```
import re
rege=r'[A-Z]{3,3}'
word='AAAD'

if( re.match(rege,word)):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

My second try was:

```
import re
rege=r'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
word='AAAD'

if( re.match(rege,word)):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

both regex tests give the answer 'yes'.  Of course I can check len(word) but, this part of regex will be part of more difficult regex expression and I do not want to use structure like

```
if(re.match(word[0:2],r'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]')):
   if(re.match(word[3]=='-')):
     if....:
       if....:
          ....
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use anchors:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

`^` will match the beginning of the string, `$` will match the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Z]{3}$
```

will do the magic for you

According to you [A-Z]{3} should work, but this only means to check whether the string to be tested contains `three letters`. `Not exactly three letters`. The string may have more letters as well.

Thus my regex will check number of letters from starting of the string to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
^[A-Z]{3}$
```

as they specify the beginning and the ending of the line, making sure nothing else is in there.